# How are KKT necessary conditions deduced?

Tags: optimization

I am trying to understand and remember the conditions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions) but I cannot yet understand them. You could take any example like [here](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/find-points-satisfying-kkt-necessary-conditions-for-the-followingproblemminimizesubject-to-q346518) to explain or more theretical slant with proper references. My lecturer is just stating that they are the necessary conditions but I cannot understand why, please, explain. I can see that when $m=0$, it is the Lagrange -multiplier case.

From the Wikipedia:

[image]

where you can see the $m$.

Comment: Chapter 5 of Stephen Boyd's book on convex optimization explains this really well. 
http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: @NickAlger: thank you, will take some time to read that.